# Nifi:Automatizied nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I  have  attribute names like  startDate:2017-09-07 and endDate:2017-09-16 i want to  reitrive  data  with  this parameters and  after writing response into the  base  i  want to change  this  parameter i  mean (startDate:2017-09-07 and endDate:2017-09-16  with 2017-09-17  and  2017-09-24) i tried  this  ecmascript code:

```
 var OutputStreamCallback = Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback");
var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");

Date.prototype.isValid = function () {
    return (Object.prototype.toString.call(this) === "[object Date]")
        && !isNaN(this.getTime());
};
function addDays(date, days) {
    var result =new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    var dateFormated = result.toISOString().substr(0,10);
    return formatDate(dateFormated);
}
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
var startDate = startDate.getValue(),
    endDate = endDate.getValue(),
    parametr=parameter.getValue(),
    count=count.getValue();
var flowFile = session.crete();

var  param=8;


    var endDate = addDays(end, param*count);
    var startDate = formatDate(newStart);
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'startDate', startDate);
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'endDate', endDate);

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

but  i  don't  know   how can i make  my  code  known  when it  should  increase **count**  in  order  to  change endDate and  startTdate  manually and  replace  it  with  valid  startDate and EndDate 
is  there any  service  or  processor  i can  use  to simplify this task?

Comment: is  there any  way  i can  fiund  how  many  times  processor  is  started and  use it  in my  code?i  want to use   cron sheduling and  it  would  be  helpful  because  i  would  set  my  count attribute to this  parameter

Comment: store your `count` in the database for example and read&increment it when you need.

Comment: there  is  no any different way  i can't do  it,  i  use  hdfs  not mysql  and related databases

Comment: store it in hdfs.

Comment: can  you reccommend me  any  alternative  way , i am  new  at  nifi and hdfs,  i mean  if  it is  possible  to solve  this taks  inside  nifi  capabilities

Comment: nifi has a built in DistributedMapCacheServer + DistributedMapCacheClient  and processors to write and read cache. DistributedMapCacheServer you can point to a local directory to be persistent, so after nifi restart the stored values will be restored.

Comment: In this case  i will  have to  write new attribute  values  by  hand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155517/discussion-between-sally-tkhilaishvili-and-daggett).

Comment: Unfortanetely, I can't  understand  your advice clearly

Comment: as i understand you need to store endDate or counter somewhere and later read and increment the value and store new value. nifi itself is not a storage. you can store value in database, hdfs file, local file, persistent cache server, etc. nifi itself persists only flow files.

Comment: ok  it  measn i  can stor  my attributes  in cash  server and  then increment  them.

Comment: By  cahnce  do  you  know If my nifi is secure i will have to use ssl Context service inside DistributedMapCashServer service or i can get rid of without it?( i use  nifi  folder for persistennt  directory)